# Trouble making a decision from an ajax request response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an ajax request with jquery to check whether a username is taken or not in a database and changing text inside a div (in this case a div with `id="wnguser"`). I am able to get the response from the **php** script and the text does appear where it should (I `echo` one of two strings: **"username available"** or **"username unavailable"** from the php script). I am not able though to use the response from the php script, the variable data (in this case one of the two strings mentioned above) to make a decision.

For example the the `if()` which I marked as `//DOES NOT WORK`. Can someone tell me how to make the `if()` work or the correct way to take a decision base on the response of the php script which is one of two strings.

Thank You

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#username').keyup(function(){

            var user = $('#username').val();
            $.post('checkusername.php', {username: user}, function(data){

            $('#wnguser').html(data);

            //DOES NOT WORK
            if (data === "username available"){
                 execute some code
            }

            });

        });



        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Do a `console.log('"' + data + '"');` to see exactly what the result is.  It may have some spaces around it.

Comment: update and post your php code also in your question

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, console.log('"' + data + '"'); did the trick. The string had a line break.

Answer (score 0):

In your checkusername.php you have to give the condition instead of the current file.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (String(data).trim() === "username available"){
                 //execute some code
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
if (data == "username available"){
    execute some code
}
```

[Refer this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)